# Using response of Google Maps API distanceMatrixRequest

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get the response of a distanceMatrixRequest in a function and use it in another function, but I can't. I'm putting the response into an object inside an array, and sending that array as an argument to the other function. I get a very weird error in Firefox Developer Edition:

```
  console.log(distanceResponse); // Outputs an array of one element, which is the object
  console.log(distanceResponse[0]); // Outputs undefined
  console.log(distanceResponse[0].distance); // Outputs an error
```

If distanceResponse is an array with one element, which is not undefined, why is distanceResponse[0] undefined?
Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 39.936489, lng: -98.128644};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }

      function getDistances() {
        var waypts = [{location: 'Washington dc', stopover: true}, {location: 'virginia', stopover: true}];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
        //Services
        var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        var distanceResponse = [];
        for (var counter = 1; counter < waypts.length; counter++) {
          distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
              origins: [waypts[counter-1].location],
              destinations: [waypts[counter].location],
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
              avoidHighways: false,
              avoidTolls: false
            },
            function(response, status) {
              if (status !== 'OK') {
                alert('Error was: ' + status);
              } else {
                var results = response.rows[0].elements;
                distanceResponse.push({duration: results[0].duration.value,    distance: results[0].distance.value});
              }
            }
          );
        }
        test(distanceResponse);
      }

      function test(distanceResponse) {
        console.log(distanceResponse); // Outputs an array of one element, which is the object
        console.log(distanceResponse[0]); // Outputs undefined
        console.log(distanceResponse[0].distance); // Outputs an error
      }

    </script>
    <div id="map" style="width: 622px; height: 274px; position:relative;overflow:auto; "></div>
    <button onclick="getDistances()">Get distances</button>
    <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY-API-KEY]&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm the result of `console.log(distanceResponse);` this code and make sure you get an array with **one** element. From your code it seems that you will be getting an empty array. To confirm, try `console.log(distanceResponse.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the statement `test(distanceResponse);` will be executed before `distanceResponse` array gets any value in it. This is because the statement that pushes value to the array `distanceResponse.push` is within the callback function. To solve the issue, you need to move the function calling statement `test(distanceResponse);` inside the callback function.

The below code should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 39.936489, lng: -98.128644};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }

      function getDistances() {
        var waypts = [{location: 'Washington dc', stopover: true}, {location: 'virginia', stopover: true}];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
        //Services
        var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        var distanceResponse = [];
        for (var counter = 1; counter < waypts.length; counter++) {
          distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
              origins: [waypts[counter-1].location],
              destinations: [waypts[counter].location],
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
              avoidHighways: false,
              avoidTolls: false
            },
            function(response, status) {
              if (status !== 'OK') {
                alert('Error was: ' + status);
              } else {
                var results = response.rows[0].elements;
                distanceResponse.push({duration: results[0].duration.value,    distance: results[0].distance.value});
                test(distanceResponse);
              }
            }
          );
        }
      }

      function test(distanceResponse) {
        console.log(distanceResponse); // Outputs an array of one element, which is the object
        console.log(distanceResponse[0]); // Outputs undefined
        console.log(distanceResponse[0].distance); // Outputs an error
      }

    </script>
    <div id="map" style="width: 622px; height: 274px; position:relative;overflow:auto; "></div>
    <button onclick="getDistances()">Get distances</button>
    <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY-API-KEY]&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

And regarding the error messages you are getting now.

> `console.log(distanceResponse);`

You have initialized `distanceResponse` with an empty array `[]` at the beginning. This value is being passed to the `test` function. So you will be getting an empty array.

> `console.log(distanceResponse[0]);`

You are getting `undefined` because the array `distanceResponse` has not values in it. You can confirm it by using `console.log(distanceResponse.length);`

> `console.log(distanceResponse[0].distance);`

You are getting an error because you are trying to access a property `distance` of `undefined`.